# Between dates in quicksight

Tags: date, between, amazon-quicksight

In quicksight I have a start date filter and an end date filter.
What i am trying to do is get a between date. What i have done is built a paramater and linked a filter to the start date and the same for the end date.
This captures somewhat what I need. The only issue is, if a start date is before the start date but ends within the date paramaters it is not shown. the same goes for the end date, if the start date is between the paramaters but the end date falls outside it is not captured.
I used to use SSRS and embed paramaters in my sql but this is not possible with postgres sql? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.
What I did first was create a start date and an end date paramater
For the filter, I assigned a variable to the start date filter and had it reference before the end date paramater.
For the end date filter I had it reference after the start date paramater